# Wordpress Backend some Pages without Content

Tags: php, wordpress

on some Backend Pages I don't get any Content. This only appears at default pages like (articles, pages, etc.)
Deactivating all plugins and the white space problem in wp-config.php didn't resolve my problem. Someone else an hint?
PHP Version is PHP 5.4.23-1~dotdeb.0.

Best Regards,
Manuel

Comment: Check your logs for errors when pages won't load

Comment: Re-upload core files, wp-admin directory and wp-includes directory from a fresh WP download.